# GCC-5 installation

Tags: gcc, zypper

I would like to install gcc-5 on my local machine. But I am encountering some issues. When I type the following command:

```
sudo zypper install gcc-5
```

I got the following answer

> Loading repository data...
>
> Reading installed packages...
>
> Package 'gcc-5' not found.
>
> Resolving package dependencies...
>
> Nothing to do.

It is strange because when I type the following command:

```
cnf gcc-5
```

I got the following answer:

> Program 'gcc-5' is present in package 'gcc5', which is installed on your system.
>
> Absolute path to 'gcc-5' is '/usr/bin/gcc-5'. Please check your $PATH variable to see whether it contains the mentioned path.

And when I want to check which gcc version is installed on my computer with the following command:

```
gcc --version
```

I have the following answer:

> If 'gcc' is not a typo you can use command-not-found to lookup the package that contains it, like this:
>       cnf gcc

How do I get GCC-5 properly installed and how could I check which version is installed/used by my computer? Thank you

info: I use openSUSE with Xfce terminal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GCC 5 is installed, but the executable is called `gcc-5`, not `gcc`.

You may either create a symlink from `gcc-5` to `gcc` in `/usr/bin` (but moving `gcc` out of the way first if it exists!), or (which may be preferable since it wouldn't include messing about with things installed by a package manager), just use `gcc-5`.

For the command line, you could set up an alias:

```
alias gcc=gcc-5
```

In most Makefiles, the compiler is picked from the `CC` Makefile variable, so setting this to `gcc-5` would also work.